# Installation of Java database connectivity driver in Windows 8

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, windows-8

I am using Sql Server for the first time and trying to connect it to Netbeans. I am running Windows 8 on my system. I am trying to install JDBC driver but it does not show anything. Can someone help me install it? Any help will be appreciated.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You don't install a JDBC driver as such, you explicitly need to include it in the classpath or configuration of an application to use it (exact way varies by application, or your own program).

Some JDBC drivers (like the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver) have an installer, but that installer does nothing more than putting the files in a convenient location.

Comment: if u can provide a link or anything else to show the exact method of configuring, it'll b really helpful

Comment: @RanaUsman As I said, it depends on what you want to do (for an existing application: look at the documentation, if for an application you are developing: it is exactly the same as any other library you might use which is: include it in the classpath of your application).